# Better way to store or extract scalar int result using SSE2 intrinsic

Tags: c, sse, intrinsics, sse2

I'm wondering how load and store efficiently vars when working with SSE2.

In this example, I want to bench the `pclmulqdq` instruction (carry less multiplication, useful for polynomial arithmetic) vs plain C function, so I need the same "calling convention" that a standard function.

a and b are 16 significant bits, result will have 32 significant bits

```
#include <wmmintrin.h>

int GFpoly_mul_i(int a, int b) {

 __m128i xa = _mm_loadu_si128( (__m128i*) a);
 __m128i xb = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*) b);
 __m128i r = _mm_clmulepi64_si128(xa, xb, 0);

 _MM_ALIGN16 int result[4];
 __m128i* ptr_result = (__m128i*)result;
 _mm_store_si128(ptr_result, r);
 return result[0];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extracting the 32bit integer from the lowest part of a vector can be done easily with `_mm_cvtsi128_si32`:

```
return _mm_cvtsi128_si32(r);
```

Loading a 32bit integer into the lowest part of a vector can be done with the "opposite" operation, `_mm_cvtsi32_si128`:

```
__m128i xa = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(a);
```

Loading the integer `a` into a vector cannot be done with `_mm_loadu_si128( (__m128i*) a)`, this would cast `a` to a pointer and dereference it (reading a 128bit vector), but `a` is just an integer value and doesn't point anywhere useful, except perhaps by accident.

Comment: Neat. Thanks! Also thanks for the wrong loading, it should have been `&a`

Comment: @Proger_Cbsk with `&a` there would be a chance of it working, but it's not really proper